# treasure hunt java 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, string, 2d

I'm trying to make a treasure hunt board program where for this game, the user will explore a 10 x 10 board that will contain treasure, pirates, and an escape off the island. The goal is to escape the island with the most treasure possible. Treasure(T) - increases as more treasure is found (ie, the first treasure is +100 gold doubloons, the second is +200 gold doubloons and so on)
Pirates (P) - the more pirates you encounter the more gold doubloons they can take. (ie. the first crew is -100 gold doubloons, the second crew is -200 gold doubloons and so on)  BUT, if the player has no treasure, there is nothing to be lost.
Both (B)- If there is treasure AND pirates, the player gets half the treasure available.
Escape (X) - When a ship is seen in the distance, the user can leave the island. How do I display the values of the gold doubloons in my 2d array?

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        // create 10x10 arrays
        final int ROWS = 10, COLS = 10;
        char[][] displayMap = new char[ROWS][COLS]; //stores the map
        char[][] board = new char[ROWS][COLS];// this will display the board 

        //variales for how many pirates 
        char pirate = 'P';

        //sets the location of the pirates on the board
        int upperBound = 5, lowerBound = 0;
        int pirateRow = (int) ((Math.random() * (upperBound - lowerBound + 1))
                + lowerArea); // the pirates location
        int pirateColumn = (int) ((Math.random() * (upperBound - lowerBound + 1))
                + lowerBound); // pirates location
        int treasures = 5;

        //call loadMap to read in the map and return it
        displayMap = loadMap();

        //this will take the board and resets the board
        clearBoard(board);

        //passes board and pirate informations to displayBoard then display it
        displayBoard(board, pirate, pirateRow, pirateColumn, treasures);

        int selection = 0;
        int playAgain = 0;

        while (selection != 4) {

            // displays the menu 
            System.out.println("WELCOME TO TREASURE HUNT");
            System.out.println("1. Play Game ");
            System.out.println("2. How to Play");
            System.out.println("3. Legend");
            System.out.println("4. Exit");

            // take the input from menu 
            System.out.println("Enter your selection.");
            selection = s.nextInt();

            switch (selection) {

                case 1:
                    PlayGame();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    HowToPlay();
                    break;
                case 100:
                    Legend();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.out.println("See you again next time!");
                default:
                    System.out.println("ERORR");
                    break;

            }
            // when user input = 1
            if (selection == 1) {

                // test for valid input
                int rowNum = 0, columnNum = 0;
                boolean isValid = false;
                
                while ( !isValid) {
                    //prompt user
                }
                System.out.println("Pick a position to explore or enter 100 to"
                        + "see the legend. ");
                char row;

                // check the row input
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); // decalres scanner
                row = sc.next().charAt(0); // this will store the character input

                if (row >= 0&& row <= 99) { // this has to be a range of 0-99
                    rowNum = testRowInput(row); // this will test and return what is in the meethod

                    if (rowNum >= 0 && rowNum <= 9) { // tests if rowNum is within the range

                        // prompt user for column number / position
                        System.out.println("Pick a position to explore or enter 100 to"
                                + "see the legend. ");
                        columnNum = getIntRange(1, 10);
                        columnNum --; // this will convert column range to 0-9
                        
                        /**
                         * check if the spot has not yet been revealed, otherwise
                         * it has been explored already
                         */
                        if ( testRevealed (board, rowNum, columnNum)) {
                            sc.nextLine(); // empty row input from buffer
                            System.out.println("You have already explored there.");
                        } else {
                            isValid = true;
                        }
                    } else {
                        sc.nextLine(); // empty row input 
                        System.out.println("Nothing to see here.");
                    }
                }
            } // finished checking user input
            
            // caught by pirate / losses gold doubloons
            if ( rowNum == pirateRow ) && ( columnNum == pirateColumn)){ 
            
            board[pirateRow][[pirateColumn]] = pirate;
            
        
                  }                   
                }
            }
        
    

    /**
     *
     */
    public static void PlayGame() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int pirates = 0;
        int treasures = 0;
        System.out.println("You chose option 1. Enter the number of pirates");
        pirates = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the number of treasures.");
        treasures = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println(displayBoard);

    }

    /**
     *
     */
    public static void HowToPlay() {
        System.out.println("You chose option 2");
        System.out.println("For this game, the user will be going on a treasure"
                + " hunt. They will explore a 10 x 10 board that will contain "
                + "treasure, pirates and an escape off the island. The goal is "
                + "to escape the island with the most treasure possible. \n"
                + "Treasure(T) - increases as more treasure is found (ie, the first treasure is "
                + "+100 gold doubloons, the second is +200 gold doubloons and so on)\n"
                + "Pirates (P) - the more pirates you encounter the more gold doubloons they can take."
                + " (ie. the first crew is -100 gold doubloons, the second crew "
                + "is -200 gold doubloons and so on)  BUT, if the player has no"
                + " treasure, there is nothing to be lost.\n"
                + "Both (B)- If there is treasure AND pirates, the player gets half the treasure "
                + "available.\n"
                + "Escape (X) - When a ship is seen in the distance, the user can leave the island.");
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    public static void Legend() {
        System.out.println("****************************************");
        System.out.println("%20s " + "LEGEND");
        System.out.println("****************************************");
        System.out.println("0 - indicates that spot has not been explored yet\n"
                + "T - indicates treasure, 100 gold doubloon\n"
                + "P - indicates pirates, lose 100 gold doubloon\n"
                + "B - indicates both treasure and pirates, 50 gold doubloon\n"
                + "X - escape the island");

    }
```

```
These codes are not yet finished and I am still in process in doing it. There are 
 more methods to work on but what I am trying to work on right now, is how I can 
display how much gold doubloons the user has every time a treasure is found and 
every time they encounter a pirate or both. 

The user's position entry must be between 0 and 99, inclusive. Should look like 
this.

Positions [00 - 09]: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
Positions [10 - 19]: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
Positions [20 - 29]: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
Positions [30 - 39]: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
Positions [40 - 49]: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
Positions [50 - 59]: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
Positions [60 - 69]: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
Positions [70 - 79]: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
Positions [80 - 89]: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
Positions [90 - 99]: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: I also want to change how instead of having a final int of num of treasures and pirates, I want to be able to prompt the user for numbers of treasures and pirates

Comment: What exactly is your question? Your code also seems to have have a couple of problems, for example, the integers `pirates` and `treasures` read in `PlayGae()` are never used, and assigned to local variables within the method. Also, you can't know the treasures' values in advance, because you don't know in which order they will be discovered.

Comment: How do I display the number of "gold doubloons" as it increases by 100 when a treasure is found and decreases when a pirate is encountered.

Answer (score 0):

In this example, let `x` represent the x-coordinate of the selected cell and `y` represents the y-coordinate of the selected cell. Your code seems rather incomplete, so let `doubloons` represent the total number of doubloons held by the player during the game.

```
// We need two fields to track the number of treasures and pirates.
// These fields are effectively multipliers for the rewards and penalties
// for each treasure or pirate encountered as the game progresses

int doubloons = 0;
int treasureCount = 0;
int pirateCount = 0;

if(board[x][y] == 'T')
{
    treasureCount++;
    doubloons = doubloons + (treasureCount * 100);
}
else if(board[x][y] == 'P')
{
    pirateCount++;
    doubloons = doubloons - (pirateCount * 100);
}
else if(board[x][y] == 'B')
{
    treasureCount++;
    pirateCount++;
    doubloons = doubloons + (treasureCount * 50);
}
else if(board[x][y] == 'X')
{
    // whatever your end game scenario is supposed to be
}
else
{
    // whatever is supposed to happen when there's no treasure, no
    // pirates and no escape
}
```

Please restrict any follow up questions to the specific issue of how to keep track of treasure and pirates, since that seems to be the issue at hand. Stack Overflow tries to stick with a "one question, one accepted answer" format, so if you have more unrelated (or even semi-related) questions, please post them as a separate question so as not to confuse the presentation.